# How to fix this error in netbeans?

Tags: c, netbeans

I get this error message. I tried to get the right things with CYGWIN, did I do something wrong? Do you need more information?

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c'
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello\.d
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello/.d
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/playing_with_c.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/playing_with_c build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello\ world.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o  
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: recipe for target `dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/playing_with_c.exe' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c/main.c:14: multiple definition of `_main'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello world.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Liam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playing with c/hello world.c:3: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/playing_with_c.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the main method in multiple places: main.c:14 and at hello world.c:3.

A program can have only 1 main method.

Either remove one of those files from the project, or remove one of the main method definitions.